# Cómo imprimir comillas dobles (") en un TextView de una aplicación android

Tags: android, textview, ascii

En la IU de la app Android que estoy programando tengo un *TextView* al que le coloco un *String* que tengo alojado en mi archivo `string.xml`. El problema es que dicho *String* tiene comillas dobles en su interior, las cuales no aparecen una vez que instalo la app en mi celular(Redmi 7a) ni en el emulador(Pixel 2 XL).

Después de investigar sustituí las comillas por su código ASCII de la siguiente manera: `&#34;` pero siguen sin mostrarse las comillas. La versión de Android Studio que estoy utilizando es la 4.1.1

Muchas gracias de antemano comunidad.

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner \"?

Comment: como lo tratas de imprimir en el TextView, agrega el còdigo por favor.

Comment: Acabo de poner \" y funciono perfectamente, gracias. Perdón por no poner el código, pero es que el navegador renderiza las comillas en lugar de poner el número ascii que escribo, o sea, lo que pongo a continuación entre parentesis, pero sin el espacio intermedio (& #34;)